# Fetch request, authorization

Tags: html

In my web browser developer tools, I am trying a fetch request.
and am receiving a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

I know I have the correct credentials because it works in postman. Can you help me understand what is wrong? Maybe is the syntax?

I assume the error is within
`{Authorization:'Basic YWIamnottypingouttherestofmycreds'}`
but I have tried every variation of this, ie:

```
{'Authorization':'Basic YWIamnottypingouttherestofmycreds'}
{Authorization:Basic YWIamnottypingouttherestofmycreds}
{'Authorization':Basic YWIamnottypingouttherestofmycreds}
```

```
fetch("http:/someoneelsesite.com",{mode:"no-cors",headers:{Authorization:'Basic YWIamnottypingouttherestofmycreds'}}).then (a => a.text()).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Try also adding `credentials: "include"` in your options object

Comment: adding "credentials:"include" forces me to physically sign in, (with a username and password) which I know the values for, but isnt my authorization basic .... already passing?

Comment: if i physically log in with creds, i get the error - Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http:someoneelsesite.com with MIME type application/xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/(somenumbershere) for more details.

Comment: yes, this is because you are not allowed to use `fetch` (or xhr) to request a resource on an origin that is not your own, unless the responding server sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response